# Combine entities in xmltex

Tags: xmltex

How to code the combine entities unicode like the below example;

The symbol `ò̰`. This character contains `tipa` package. The corresponding symbol combine entity is 00F2, 0330.

How to map the below command for the above entity code in xmltex.

I have provided my MWE for your reference.

```
%%Sample.tex%%
\def\xmlfile{sample.xml}
\input xmltex

%%Sample.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article SYSTEM "JATS-journalpublishing1.dtd">
<article>
<body>
<p>The combine entity sample &#x00F2;, &#x0330;.</p>
</body>
</article>

%%Sample.xmt%%


\XMLentity{TeX}{\TeX}
\XMLentity{LaTeX}{\LaTeX}

%%%%Main Root Tag%%%%
\XMLelement{article}%
    {}%
    {\documentclass{article}%
    \begin{document}}%
    {\end{document}}%
%%%%

%%%%Main Root Tag%%%%
\XMLelement{body}%
    {}%
    {}%
    {}%
%%%%





\XMLelement{p}{}{}{\par}%




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

`\UnicodeCharacter{00F2}{\textsubumlaut{\'{\i}}}%%`

Could you please check and advice.

Comment: Can you give a small xml document and a `.tex` document that illustrates your issue?

Comment: @Marijn i posted my mwe. Please advice.

Comment: Does your xml source really contain sequences like `&#x00F2;, &#x0330;`, so a unicode character number, a comma, a space, another unicode number? Or does the source contain the character `ò̰`? How do you write this character in `tipa`? What is the relevance of the last line (`\UnicodeCharacter{00F2}{\textsubumlaut{\'{\i}}}`), given that `0330` is a tilde below and not an umlaut?